# How to create a copy constructor in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, constructor, copy, copy-constructor

I'm new to Ruby and I'm programming a game where there is a class named Player and I'm having issues when trying to copy an object. My code looks something like this:

```
class Player

    attr_accessor :imprisoned
    attr_reader :name
    attr_reader :balance
    attr_accessor :freedom_card
    attr_accessor :current_box
    attr_reader :properties

    # Default constructor with no parameters
    def initialize (name = "")
        @name = name
        @imprisoned = false
        @balance = 7500
        @properties = Array.new
        @freedom_card = nil
        @current_box = nil
    end

    # Constructor with one parameter (it works)
    def self.nuevo (name)
        self.new(name)
    end

    # Copy constructor (doesn't seem to work)
    def self.copia (other_player)
        @name = other_player.name
        @imprisoned = other_player.imprisoned
        @balance = other_player.balance
        @properties = other_player.properties
        @freedom_card = other_player.freedom_card
        @current_box = other_player.current_box
        self
    end

    # ...
end
```

When testing it with this:

```
player = Player.nuevo ("John")
puts player.name
player_2 = Player.copia(player)
puts player_2.name
```

I get this:

```
John
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for ModeloQytetet::Player:Class
```

What could be the error? It also fails when using other attributes or methods from the copied object but all works fine in the original one. Thanks in advance and sorry for any English mistakes (not my first language).

Comment: Why not use [`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-dup)? `player_2 = player.dup`.

Comment: When I run your code, I get this: `John` / `Player`. Interesting question, by the way :-)

Comment: It's a university project and we have to do it like that @anothermh

Comment: @Josien you can see my answer, you get "Player" because `copia` returns `self` which is the **class** `Player`. and `Player.name = "Player"`

Comment: You should be careful with your whitespace before you develop bad habits. `m(a, b)` is a method call as the parentheses are seen as "method calling parentheses", `m (a, b)` is a syntax error because the parentheses are seen as "expression grouping parentheses" and `a, b` is not a valid expression. Things like `Player.nuevo ("John")` work by accident because the expression inside the parentheses is a single value.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh, thanks for the advice, I will be careful with that, I'm used to C++ where (i think) things like that always work

Comment: A small suggestion for the future: when you give an example, make it as brief as possible. Here, for example, including instance variables other than `@name` (and associated accessors) adds nothing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the exact piece of Qytetet I am in trouble with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
def self.copia(other_player)
  @name = other_player.name
  @imprisoned = other_player.imprisoned
  @balance = other_player.balance
  @properties = other_player.properties
  @freedom_card = other_player.freedom_card
  @current_box = other_player.current_box
  self
end
```

The `@` relate to the instance variable of the **class** `Player`. you actually do nothing, just setting some variables and return `self`, which is a **class**, not an instance

You could do it with

```
def self.copia(other_player)
  player = new(other_player.name)
  player.from(other_player)
  player
end

def from(other_player)
  @name = other_player.name
  @imprisoned = other_player.imprisoned
  @balance = other_player.balance
  @properties = other_player.properties
  @freedom_card = other_player.freedom_card
  @current_box = other_player.current_box
end
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!